# How do i convert an array of sub-array strings to an array of sub-arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How do i convert an array in **javascript**, from this format :

> ["[1,2,3]","[4,5,6]"]   to   [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]    ?

i need to get an array of sub-arrays from my array of strings(in arrays format!)

thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var input = ["[1,2,3]","[4,5,6]"];
var fullQualifiedArrayStructure = input.map(JSON.parse);
```

using map to apply a function to each element of the array. the applied function is JSON.parse, which converts a JSON string representation into an object.